MCUXpresso with MQX 4.2 : Kinetis MK64FN1M0VLQ12
I'm compiling an old Code Warrior v10.6 (Freescale) project with MQX 4.2 in MCUXpressov11.9.1 (NXP). I want to continue to use MQX 4.2 in MCUXpresso. I can't resolve the following error on the MQX files:
c:\users\pc-281\desktop\myproject\gesap\cpuc\cpuc-arm\freescale_mqx_4_2\mqx\source\psp\cortex_m\compiler\gcc_cw\comp.h:43:32: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__asm'

 43 | #define __set_BASEPRI(basePri) __asm volatile ("msr BASEPRI, %0" : : "r" (basePri))

 

C:\Users\PC-281\Desktop\myProject\GESAP\CpuC\CpuC-arm\armCpucApp\CMSIS/core_cm4.h:1557:46: error: expected ')' before '*' token

 1557 | #define NVIC ((NVIC_Type *) NVIC_BASE ) /*!< NVIC configuration struct */

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.
Best regards

I suspect it might simply be because inline assembler isn't standardized so the Codewarrior and gcc compilers may use different inline assembler syntax for your target.
